# Put ligature char to a ComboBox text

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I use a ComboBox with `DropDownStyle` set to **`DropDown`**, meaning I can insert any text, independently from ComboBox's list DataSource.

I set the DataSource to:

```
comboBox.DataSource = new List<string> {"", "oe"};
```

If I set text with ligature:

```
comboBox.Text = "œ";
```

it is immediatelly changed to the `oe` form.

Text is normally set when ligature's normalization entry does not exist in data source.

How to force to not normalize this text?

Comment: Can confirm that. Adding combobox and button, then clicking button to set text like you do will first show `oe` and second click will show `œ`, not sure why. Somehow `"œ" == "oe"` when combobox compares them and chooses latter from data source.

Comment: @Sweeper, can you tl;dr here? I found that `"oe".Equals("œ", StringComparison.InvariantCulture)` returns `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SelectedText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext) property instead of the Text property:

```
comboBox.Focus();
comboBox.SelectedText = "œ";
```

Setting the `SelectedText` value, implies sending (`SendMessage`) a `EM_REPLACESEL` message to the ComboBox's Edit control. This just substitutes the text in the Edit control: the control doesn't try to match the text entered to the elements in the list.

You could also *reset* the Text property, setting:

```
comboBox.Text = string.Empty;
comboBox.SelectedText = "œ";
```

In this case, setting the `ComboBox.Text` property raises the `TextChanged` event 3 times, when there's a previous selection, while setting the Focus (selecting the exiting text, if any) and replacing the selection, raises the event only once and only if the Text actually changes. It may be a relevant difference.

Setting the Text property, implies calling [SetWindowText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowtextw), which sends a `WM_SETTEXT` message. This will trigger the pattern matching feature, which will also cause, following the [Unicode Standard 12.1.0 Case Folding Properties](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/CaseFolding.txt), a character normalization in the case matching procedure:

> The data supports both implementations that require simple case
>   foldings (where string lengths don't change), and implementations that
>   allow full case folding (where string lengths may grow). Note that
>   where they can be supported, the full case foldings are superior: for
>   example, they allow "MASSE" and "Maße" to match.

Comment: I see why you use 'Focus' method. The main problem with 'SelectedText' is that it does not override 'Text' property. It just appends value.

I'd rather reset 'Text' property instead of using 'Focus'

Comment: I provided that method for a reason. Setting `[ComboBox].Text = string.Empty` raises the `TextChanged` event 3 times, when there's a previous selection. `[ComboBox].Focus();` plus `[ComboBox].SelectedText = "something";` only once and only if the text actually changes. Maybe it's irrelevant, maybe it's not. But now you can say *I see why you use 'Focus' method*. So you have tested both and now you have this information. I'll add this detail to the answer

Comment: I found another issue. Using `SelectedText` sets `SelectedValue` and `SelectedItem` with null, whilst `Text` doesn't. So you need to remember and restore them.

Comment: Nope. `SelectedItem` is null when you change the Text in any way and the new Text doesn't match any item in the list.